# Is Google Adsense the best way to monetize?

Tags: google-adsense

I run a website and have some traffic.

Since around late 2017, many other publishers started to contact me. They said that they can optimize my revenue and no need to do any extra work, just replace the Adsense code with their code.

These people have a lot of "concepts", however, I don't quite understand the fundamental logic.

If ads business is about getting buyers and sellers, why smaller companies can do better than Google?

Any discussion on this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We can do better than AdSense" is a very common selling point for alternative ad brokers.  In theory, somebody should be able to do better than AdSense.   However, I haven't found an alternative for ads on my site that works better than AdSense.

When you get these offers you should:

1. Research the company.  Look for online reviews and if other folks have had success with them.
2. Test their ads on 10% your site.  Ideally random pages from your site or alternate over time between Google AdSense.  You want to be able to compare revenue in an A/B test.
3. If they do better than Google, use them more.  Keep Google running at 10% at least for a few months, just so you can continue to compare.

At the very least, it is always a good idea to have another ad network lined up ready to go or running minimally.  What if your AdSense revenue tanks?  What if AdSense closes your account?  It happens.

If you use an Ad Manager on your site such as Google DFP, it makes it very easy to set up ad tests.  You don't have to program anything or swap our JavaScript snippets.   You just enter their JS into the ad manager, and set up rules for how often they show up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "smaller companies", but there are some successful entrepreneurial companies that offer tools that help you with your Google Ads. An example is a company founded in my hometown Linz (SMEC), who provides a solution to manage your eCommerce store. I am sure there are plenty of others who offer successful tools. By the way, I have not ever used the product mentioned, and I don't know to what degree it may help you - I am not here to advertise and promote a specific product. If you are referring to these kinds of solutions, I believe they are legit, and they do help you.

However, if you are talking about SEO or PPC companies who promise you the world, without having to do anything - then you better stay away. Your mama probably told you that nothing is free in life - and she is and will always be right. If you can give additional examples I may be able to say to you right away if the product/service offered is legit or you are being ripped off.